# Parse JSON returned by twitch

Tags: c#, twitch

I am currently developing a twitch bot that monitors the users in the chat.

This site link will give you every user in the twitch stream / irc chat:
http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/lirik/chatters.

For example I have given you lirik's chat.
I need to get the folowing from the site:

```
"_links": {},
  "chatter_count": 0,
  "chatters": {
    "moderators": [],
    "staff": [],
    "admins": [],
    "global_mods": [],
    "viewers": []
```

Here is the code I have written so far to connect to the site and read the text:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
System.IO.Stream stream = web.OpenRead("http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/lirik/chatters");
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
{
    String text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

How can I turn the text from the site into multiple arrays?

Comment: when actually you would like to stop it and create a new array?

Comment: @Slashy I would like to retrieve the array, or turn it into an array in my program. I need hold of the text in an array.

Comment: i understand but you're getting the content as string. So we would have to sort the string a split every time some content to array. that's why im asking when would you like to stop? each `,`?

Comment: Yes @Slashy Sorry, didn't understand what you where asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually looking for Desiarializing Json into C# class.

So you should create class that describes your json structure ant then just use this kind of code:

```
YourClass jsonDeserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text); //it's your text here
```

For more information of how you should write your class you can [read msdn](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwicnqjg3avHAhWBhHIKHUN0BZc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fbb412179(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=5IbPVZycFoGJygPD6JW4CQ&usg=AFQjCNGO3SgCv8eXsRR1Gw9cYBuOSA71BQ&sig2=XX8RV6nssNm3R3wQAMUF-Q&bvm=bv.99804247,d.bGQ&cad=rja).